# Combining indexes in an array PHP

Tags: php

I can't quite seem to grasp how I would go about combining the indexes in this array. Below is an example of the array. Any help, resources, or direction would be appreciated.

```
  $array_one = array(
    10 => array(0 => 2/3-AM),
    10 => array(0 => AUT-PR),
    1195 => array(0 => 1/2-AM),
    1258 => array(0 => GR-1),
    1195 => array(0 => 1/7-PM),
    );
```

I'd like for it to look like this:

```
   $array_one = array(
    10 => array(0 => 2/3-AM, AUT-PR),
    1195 => array(0 => 1/2-AM, 1/7-PM),
    1258 => array(0 => GR-1),
    );
```

[var_dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgpwK.png)

Comment: Your input array is not even possible since you can't have duplicate keys in the first place.

Comment: Indent/organize your arrays before posting next time please.

Comment: @Sammitch well whenever I print_r($array_one) that's what it reads?! Sorry I'm new to this. I'm getting the array from a CSV if that matters?

Comment: @user9530586 Please edit your question to include the output of `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of your input array.

Comment: @Progman i added a screenshot to post.

Comment: That screenshot shows multiple var_dumps not just one. Possibly in a loop. That is not the same as you state in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Making assumptions from your screenshot, I think you meant your input array is:

```
$input = array(
    array(10 => array(0 => '2/3-AM')),
    array(10 => array(0 => 'AUT-PR')),
    array(1195 => array(0 => '1/2-AM')),
    array(1258 => array(0 => 'GR-1')),
    array(1195 => array(0 => '1/7-PM')),
);
```

To get this into your target format:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $output[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($output);
```

This results in:

```
array(3) {
    [10]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(6) "2/3-AM"
        [1]=> string(6) "AUT-PR"
    }
    [1195]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(6) "1/2-AM"
        [1]=> string(6) "1/7-PM"
    }
    [1258]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(4) "GR-1"
    }
}
```